# нет правила для сборки цели clean и install

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu, gnumake

В папке orbitToolsDemo лежит проект:

```
mkf           //  интересует этот makefile

./orbitTools/core:
cEci.cpp  cJulian.cpp  coord.cpp  coreLib.h   cSite.h   cTLE.h       cVector.h     globals.cpp  stdafx.h
cEci.h    cJulian.h    coord.h   cSite.cpp             cTLE.cpp  cVector.cpp  exceptions.h  globals.h    stdafx.cpp

./orbitTools/orbit:
cNoradBase.cpp  cNoradSDP4.cpp  cNoradSGP4.cpp  cOrbit.cpp  cSatellite.cpp  orbitLib.h    stdafx.cpp
cNoradBase.h    cNoradSDP4.h    cNoradSGP4.h    cOrbit.h    cSatellite.h           stdafx.h

./orbitToolsDemo:
main.cpp  resource.h  stdafx.cpp  stdafx.h
```

привожу mkf:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++1y
PATH_CORE=./orbitTools/core/
PATH_ORBIT=./orbitTools/orbit/

.PHONY : all clean install

all : orbit

orbit : cEci.o cJulian.o coord.o cSite.o cTLE.o cVector.o globals.o \
    cNoradBase.o cNoradSDP4.o cNoradSGP4.o cOrbit.o cSatellite.o \
    main.o stdafx.o
    g++ cEci.o cJulian.o coord.o cSite.o cTLE.o cVector.o globals.o \
             cNoradBase.o cNoradSDP4.o cNoradSGP4.o cOrbit.o cSatellite.o \
             main.o stdafx.o -o orbit

clean :
    rm -rf *.o orbit

cEci.o : $(PATH_CORE)cEci.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)cEci.cpp

cJulian.o : $(PATH_CORE)cJulian.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)cJulian.cpp

coord.o : $(PATH_CORE)coord.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)coord.cpp

cSite.o : $(PATH_CORE)cSite.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)cSite.cpp

cTLE.o : $(PATH_CORE)cTLE.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)cTLE.cpp

cVector.o : $(PATH_CORE)cVector.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)cVector.cpp

globals.o : $(PATH_CORE)globals.cpp $(PATH_CORE)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_CORE)globals.cpp

cNoradBase.o : $(PATH_ORBIT)cNoradBase.cpp $(PATH_ORBIT)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_ORBIT)cNoradBase.cpp

cNoradSDP4.o : $(PATH_ORBIT)cNoradSDP4.cpp $(PATH_ORBIT)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_ORBIT)cNoradSDP4.cpp

cNoradSGP4.o : $(PATH_ORBIT)cNoradSGP4.cpp $(PATH_ORBIT)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_ORBIT)cNoradSGP4.cpp

cOrbit.o : $(PATH_ORBIT)cOrbit.cpp $(PATH_ORBIT)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_ORBIT)cOrbit.cpp

cSatellite.o : $(PATH_ORBIT)cSatellite.cpp $(PATH_ORBIT)stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) $(PATH_ORBIT)cSatellite.cpp

main.o : ./orbitToolsDemo/main.cpp ./orbitToolsDemo/stdafx.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) ./orbitToolsDemo/main.cpp

stdafx.o : ./orbitToolsDemo/stdafx.cpp #./orbitTools/core/coreLib.h ./orbitTools/orbit/orbitLib.h
    g++ $(CFLAGS) ./orbitToolsDemo/stdafx.cpp

install:
    install ./orbit /home/tree_js
```

все собирается, запускается... однако make clean и make install не работают:

make clean

make install

, дескать, "нет правила для сборки цели clean". Что не так?

версия make: GNU Make 3.82

версия ОС: Linux version 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 (builder@kbuilder.dev.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9) (GCC) )

Comment: 1. приведите, пожалуйста, полностью команду, на которую получаете ответ «нет правила для…» и укажите, в каком каталоге вы её запускаете. 2. приведите, пожалуйста, версию используемой программы make. 3. укажите, пожалуйста, название дистрибутива используемой операционной системы.

Comment: если приведённый файл называется `mkf`, то *gnu/make* его не использует.

Comment: ну проект то собрался, все нормально... или вы о чем

Comment: Может там есть еще `makefile` или `Makefile`? Вообще-то для `mkf` надо вызывать `make -f mkf ...`

Comment: @xperious, я о том, что этот файл либо вообще не используется, либо вызывается (**не** подключается директивой include) из другого файла. в котором нет целей clean и install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

программа *gnu/make*, если ей не указан файл с правилами, пытается использовать [такие имена файлов](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html) (именно в таком порядке): `GNUmakefile`, `makefile` и `Makefile`.

в том каталоге, где вы запускаете программу *gnu/make*, вероятно, и присутствует файл с одним из перечисленных выше имён.

а файл с именем `mkf` не используется (по умолчанию).

для того, чтобы указать конкретный файл, можно передать программе *gnu/make* опцию `-f имя_файла`. например:

```
$ make -f mkf clean
```

Comment: всем спасибо... да, надо было make -f mkf clean... вроде ерунда, но нагуглить не смог сам

Comment: @xperious, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, принятым («галочка») слева от ответа.