# объектные файлы в другой каталог

Tags: makefile, gnumake

в продолжении темы [вопрос про makefile](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517166)

подскажите, какими командами можно добиться, чтобы объектные файлы создавались не в директории с makefile-ом, а в другой директории?

вот, допустим, делаем `gcc -c hello.c` и появляется объектный файл `hello.o` в директории с makefile. как сделать, чтобы появлялся `hello1.o` в директории `./objects`?

Comment: спасибо... только тяжко пока такие makefile из вашего примера читать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ввиду того, что это совершенно не «общепринятая практика», «командами» получить желаемое, насколько мне известно, невозможно. придётся в мэйкфайле к имени каждого файла дописывать нужный вам путь. [пример такого изменения](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1892934/4827341).

и компилятору тоже надо явно указывать путь:

```
$ gcc -o objects/hello.o -c hello.c
```

---

что ориентировочно надо сделать:

1. для удобства манипуляций добавить (где-нибудь в начале файла) переменную, содержащую путь к каталогу с объектными файлами:

   ```
   dir = objects
   ```
2. упоминания каждого объектного файла предварить этой переменной. т.е.:

   ```
   cEci.o
   ```

   заменить на:

   ```
   $(dir)/cEci.o
   ```

   и т.д.

и ещё для удобства я бы предложил дважды встречающееся перечисление всех объектных файлов тоже перенести в переменную. вместо:

```
cEci.o cJulian.o ... main.o stdafx.o
```

написать:

```
$(objects)
```

тогда проще будет и префикс добавить «одним махом» ко всем этим именам:

```
objects_list = cEci.o cJulian.o ... main.o stdafx.o
objects = $(addprefix $(dir)/,$(objects_list))
```

эти две строки тоже где-нибудь в начале файла можно поместить.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ make VPATH=.. -C objects -f../Makefile
```

Данный способ позволяет ничего не менять в Makefile, но не всегда срабатывает. Текущий каталог оказывается другой, поэтому если есть подключаемые файлы с путём относительно него, иногда нужно компилятору указать пути их поиска. Например, если c-файл тоже является промежуточной целью, как при использовании `lex` и `yacc`.

```
$  CFLAGS=-I.. make VPATH=.. -C objects -f../Makefile
```

В самом Makefile CFLAGS должно меняться с помощью `+=`, чтобы сохранить оба присвоения.

Все новые файлы создаются в objects, но если в текущем каталоге уже есть объектные файлы и они новее исходников, они будут использованы для линковки. Чтобы конечные и промежуточные целевые файлы не искались по [`VPATH`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#General-Search), можно использовать директиву [`vpath`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Selective-Search) внутри Makefile для выборочного расширения поиска исходников.
Предлагаю следующую заготовку для начала Makefile:

```
SRC := $(dir $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))# каталог где находится этот Makefile (если до этой директивы не было include)
# для компиляции из другого каталога (где будут временные файлы и результат)
vpath %.c $(SRC)
vpath %.h $(SRC)
vpath Makefile $(SRC)
```

Теперь компилировать можно командой:

```
make -C objects -f../Makefile
```

Answer (score 0):

Небольшой пример makefile для небольших проектов, Здесь все *.c файлы собираются в один проект также учитываются зависимотсь *.c файлов от *.h

```
EXEC=gtk_test
OBJ_CATALOG=.obj/
DEPEND_CATALOG=.depend/

SOURCE=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.c,$(OBJ_CATALOG)%.o,$(SOURCE))
DEPEND=$(patsubst %.c,$(DEPEND_CATALOG)%.d,$(SOURCE))

CXX=gcc
CFLAGS=-g2 -Wall -I. `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0`
LDFLAGS=-g2
LIB=`pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`

$(EXEC):$(OBJS)
  $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)

$(OBJ_CATALOG)%.o:%.c
  $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(DEPEND_CATALOG)%.d:%.c
  $(CXX) -MM -I. $< | sed -e '1s/^/.obj\//' > $@

include $(DEPEND)

.PHONY:clean
clean:
  -rm -f $(EXEC) *~ $(OBJ_CATALOG)*.o $(DEPEND_CATALOG)*.d
```