# Makefile, компилировать объектные файлы в отдельную папку

Tags: c++, makefile

Как сделать шаблонное правило в makefile чтобы файлы с исходными кодами собирались в объектные файлы и помещались в отдельную папку? Я имею множество исходных файлов которые находятся в множестве различных поддиректорий. Т.к. цели и зависимости находятся в разных директориях, то шаблонное правило у меня создать не получается.

Comment: по нынешним то временам, make это как ассемблер, лучше использовать, что-нибудь высокоуровневое: cmake, qmake, а они уж могут и makefile сделать

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [объектные файлы в другой каталог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/517179/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3)

Comment: Руками прописать лень?

Comment: @PavelGridin, *по нынешним то временам, make это как ассемблер* — использовать программу make только для запуска компилятора — это примерно как гвозди микроскопом забивать. да, конечно, для этого лучше подойдут «высокоуровневые молотки», ну а «микроскопу» логично оставить его «микроскопические» задачи.

Comment: Можно воспользоваться готовым [проектом](https://github.com/deminets/unimake/), либо подёргать из него решения.