# Почему не работают условные операторы в Makefile?

Tags: linux, gcc, makefile

Есть у меня вот такой вот Makefile:

```
BIN=bin/Linux

OBJ=obj/Linux

EXEC=runner

SOURCES=auto_decltype.cpp beginend.cpp const_expr.cpp enumclass.cpp \
final_override.cpp foreach.cpp init_list.cpp literal.cpp main.cpp \
move_copy.cpp multithreading.cpp no_except.cpp numericlimit.cpp \
variabletemplate.cpp version.cpp

OBJS=$(SOURCES:%.cpp=$(OBJ)/%.o)

.PHONY: all clean

ifdef release
.INTERMEDIATE: $(OBJS)
endif

all: $(BIN)/$(EXEC)


$(OBJS): $(OBJ)/%.o: %.cpp test_functions.h | $(OBJ)
    @echo "Compiling file $<..."
ifeq ($<, 'multithreading.cpp')
    g++ -o $@ -c -pthread $<
else
    g++ -o $@ -c $<
endif

$(BIN)/$(EXEC): $(OBJS) | $(BIN)
    @echo "Linking..."
    g++ -o $@ -pthread $(OBJS)
    @echo "Build succeeded!"

$(BIN) $(OBJ):
    mkdir $@

clean:
    -rm -rf $(BIN)
    -rm -rf $(OBJ)
```

В нём два условных оператора, и ни один из них не работает: Makefile отрабатывает так, будто ни одно из условий не проходит. Первый из них - это попытка передать опцию release при вызове команды `make release=''`, второй - в зависимости от имени файла включать или не включать опцию -pthread.

Comment: Потому что они выполняются в момент чтения файла, и никакого $< ещё нет

Comment: Проверил с помощью ifdef / ifndef - так и есть. Со вторым понятно. А почему не работает первый вариант?

Comment: 1. несвязанные вопросы надо задавать отдельно. 2. [mcve]

Comment: по поводу второго вопроса: стоит воспользоваться [условной фукнцией](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Conditional-Functions.html). что-то вроде: `... $(if $(filter $<,multithreading.cpp),-pthread) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

помещение [специальной цели `.INTERMEDIATE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules) внутрь условного оператора `ifdef` отлично работает.

---

[минимальный самодостаточный воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
$ cat GNUmakefile 
ifdef cond
.INTERMEDIATE: 1.int
endif

1.fin: 1.int
    cat $< > $@

1.int: 1.src
    cat $< > $@

clean:
    -rm -f 1.*
    touch 1.src
```

очищаем текущий каталог от результатов предыдущих тестов:

```
$ make clean
rm -f 1.*
touch 1.src
```

передаём пустую переменную `cond` — промежуточный файл `1.int`, как и ожидалось, **не** удаляется:

```
$ make 1.fin cond=
cat 1.src > 1.int
cat 1.int > 1.fin
```

очищаем текущий каталог от результатов предыдущего теста:

```
$ make clean
rm -f 1.*
touch 1.src
```

передаём **не**пустую переменную `cond` — промежуточный файл `1.int`, как и ожидалось, благополучно удаляется:

```
$ make 1.fin cond=.
cat 1.src > 1.int
cat 1.int > 1.fin
rm 1.int
```

---

общие соображения: хотя разбрасывание артефактов сборки по разным каталогам, вроде бы, и практикуется разработчиками **некоторых** *ide*, такую практику вряд ли можно считать общепринятой.

в личном проекте, несомненно, каждый сам себе хозяин. а вот для совместной разработки, вероятно, лучше придерживаться более наглядной (и более распространённой, а значит и более ожидаемой) практики: помещать артефакты сборки в том же каталоге, где располагаются и исходные файлы, из которых эти артефакты были получены.

Comment: А какие IDE так НЕ делают? Разве что старый C++ Builder, но даже они потом убрали помойку в папках проектов.

Comment: я вообще не программист, соответственно, не пользуюсь *ide* (но ежедневно, если не ежечасно, пользуюсь интерпретаторм *gnu/make*). когда-то столкнулся с [подобным странным пожеланием](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/517179/178576), и где-то вычитал, что практику раскладывания артефактов по отдельным каталогам некоторые начинающие программисты пытаются «притащить в реальный мир», наблюдая её в работе **некоторых** *ide* (не помню уже, какие примеры был приведены, вроде бы, среди них фигурировали программы от компании *microsoft*).

Comment: Это не "странное пожелание", а практика разработки, в том числе коллективной; вспомните, как устроена папка `/usr`. Или любые библиотеки C++. Или как организована структура проектов на Java (там это вообще один из двух принудительных вариантов, это вшито в язык). Когда программа состоит из одного-двух файлов исходного кода, это действительно излишне. Но, например, при работе с системой контроля версий гораздо удобнее задавать настройки для папок, чем для выборочного набора файлов, который ещё и меняться в ходе разработки будет (например, у меня в Subversion все папки `bin` и `obj` игнорятся).